# How to change 3 meter to pixel distance?

Tags: matlab, graphics, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a 3D object and I need to project it relative to a 2D image, which is captured 3m away with a camera. When I tried to make a projection matrix I found that I need to state the camera position from the object (3m) and the height of the Camera above the ground (1m). Thus, I need to change these values, measured in meters, to pixels so that they can be  used in a projection matrix.

I need to do the computation in Matlab. Any pointers?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you might want to clarify that you're talking about analyzing an image, rather than sizing it for an output device.  You'll need to know the pixel scale of the image (degrees per pixel), the distance between the object and the camera (which gives the angle subtended by the object), and possibly the orientation of the object, if not measured parallel to the image plane.

Comment: @Amr Ramadan: perhaps you should explain what your goal is for this conversion...

Comment: I agree with Jim, you need to be more specific. If you are talking about an image captured by a camera, you'll get into a quite challenging subject. Camera calibration to translate real-word coordinates to/from pixels can be a pain.

Comment: i need to make a projection for a 3D model and need i need to determine the values of the translation matrix 
the 3D object is away from the camera ( 3meters ) on Z axis, X and y = 0 
so i need to change 3 meter to a pixel unit :) to be used in calculations

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't follow which of these applies: a) You have an object sitting at 3m from your camera and you want to know how it would look on your screen? Or b) you have an image of a 3D object on your screen and you want to know how it would look at 3m from a camera? Or c) something else (in which case: elaborate).

Comment: perhaps @Amr Ramadan can rewrite the question in such a way that it explains what he's trying to do...?

Comment: I have 3D object and i need to project it relative to 2D image
which captured 3m away with a camera and when i tried to make a projection matrix i found that i need to state the camera position from the object (3m) and the height of the Camera above the ground (1m) so i need to change this values which measured in meters to pixels values to be used in projection matrix

Comment: Please note the importance of asking a _good_ question ahead of time; there are now three answers given, and none of them guessed your intentions correctly. :) Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for some suggestions on how to write good questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1 metre = 39.3700787 inches so `dpi * distance_in_meters / 39.3700787`

Obviously you will need to know the DPI of the output device.

Comment: This only works for scanners. For imaging devices using lenses (such as camera's) dpi is a useless measure.

Comment: in the original question, no one has mentioned lenses or cameras. To Quentin and to me it was a question about the length of a segment on screen.

Answer (score 0):

get(0,'ScreenPixelsPerInch')

Gives you the missing ingredient in Quentin's solution.